# C#: Update datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystemwatcher

I have a C# application with a datagrid in windows form. I need to monitor a directory (am using FileSystemWatcher) and refresh the datagrid with list of files in the directory. I am not sure how I can set up the interface to do so? Calling the monitorDirectory() from the windows-form Load() does not seem to work as Load is called only once in the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could update your grid within the OnChanged or OnRenamed event handlers of your FileSystemWatcher.

The example at the link below is handling the events within a Console application.
[MSDN FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Detecting File Changes with FileSystemWatcher](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/FileSystemWatcher.aspx) has a good example of how to use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7t1d0ky(v=VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to events from the FileSystemWatcher object. The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) posts some recommendations on how to do this.

Essentially, right before calling MonitorDirectory(), you should subscribe to the Changed, Created, Deleted, and Renamed events of your FileSystemWatcher.

Answer (score 0):

Full Code

Add a Form1 to your project

Replace Form1.Designer.cs with

```
namespace Test
{
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.fileSystemWatcher1 = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.fileSystemWatcher1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 150);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // fileSystemWatcher1
        // 
        this.fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        this.fileSystemWatcher1.Path = "c:\\Temp";
        this.fileSystemWatcher1.SynchronizingObject = this;
        this.fileSystemWatcher1.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.fileSystemWatcher1_CreatedDeletedChanged);
        this.fileSystemWatcher1.Created += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.fileSystemWatcher1_CreatedDeletedChanged);
        this.fileSystemWatcher1.Deleted += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(this.fileSystemWatcher1_CreatedDeletedChanged);
        this.fileSystemWatcher1.Renamed += new System.IO.RenamedEventHandler(this.fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(370, 301);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.fileSystemWatcher1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private System.IO.FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher1;
}
}
```

Replace Form1.cs with

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void PopulateGrid()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(fileSystemWatcher1.Path);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dir.GetFiles();
    }


    private void fileSystemWatcher1_CreatedDeletedChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateGrid();
    }



    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateGrid();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PopulateGrid();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: who calls the FileSystemWatcher? Thanks

Comment: If I understand the question. Nobody calls it, the control, raises events on its own to let you know something has occurred.  So to test the code above add a grid and fileSystemWatcher control to the form, then add a file to the path you ware watching.